# Virtual user mail server setup

Tags: server, postfix, mail, dovecot

I have tried multiple times to setup a mail server that uses a mysql backend on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I have used this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin (and a few others previously that I cannot remember).

I keep getting bugs, not being able to login, smtp failing and all those things, so my question is: where can I find an easy to follow guide as the only mail server I have ever got working is this one: https://samhobbs.co.uk/raspberry-pi-email-server only that server does not use virtual users/.

Here is my complete log (from the first step to me just copying all the guides configs because it didn't work: hastebin com/kekezivezo.xml as I just copied all commands and only changed the domain name I dont care if there are any passwords/usernames/ect in there)

Answer (score 0):

Installed the server using this guide recently on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There are a few mistakes in the guide:

1. You don't need some packs, some you should rename (This is an Ubuntu 16.04 only problem).
2. `nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`

   ```
   service imap-login {
     inet_listener imap {
       port = 0
   }
   ```

   You need to add here the `address = your ip`, or `dovecot` won't open a socket.
3. There is a mistake in `dovecot-mysql`config in the guide. They recommending to uncomment `disable_plaintext_auth = yes`. But doing this is what doesn't allow you to login via mail clients through IMAP.
4. Also an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS only trouble is, that while installing `MySQL` I have installed a password validation plugin. Thus, it wont allow you to create a 'usermail' user with a weak password from the guide. You should create user like 'dovepost' and with a strong password and change it in those 3 mysql config files for postfix and dovecot that you create in the beginning of the guide.